# How can I tell which of my disks needs repairing in WIndows 8?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, ssd

I've recently purchased a Dell Vostro 470 and added a Samsung 830 256GB SSD. I;ve done a clean install of Windows 8 onto the SSD. So now I have two disks, the SSD as C: and the 500GB disk as D:.

The Action Centre keeps popping up telling me to "Restart now to repair disks". When I click restart, it just boots back to Windows. I see no signs of any repair happening, then when I'm back in Windows, the notification will pop up again in the Action Centre.

How can I tell which disk Windows is concerned with and how can I help Windows to actually perform the repair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scan disks or run `chkdsk` on your disks.

1. Using Windows GUI:

   1. In File Explorer right-click a disk.
   2. Click **Tools** tab.
   3. Click **Check now** button in **Error-checking** group (the first group on the tab).
2. Using command-line utility:

   1. Open Command Prompt with Administrative privileges.
   2. Type `chkdsk /f D:` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to check disk D: for errors.
      In place of `D:` use other disk letters to check them.
   3. To check disk C: run:
      `chkdsk /f C:`

Checking system disk, C:, requires a reboot.

If you want to check for bad sectors on the disk, either add `/r` option to `chkdsk` command, or select **Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors** if using GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for bad sectors on your disks. There are many utilities out there that can scan for bad sectors.

I use this:
http://hddscan.com/

If there are bad sectors on a disk then it will fail eventually and your data with it.
You should back up data from a disk that is failing to another hard drive.

Your 500GB disk seems suspect, I hope it's ok.

Good luck!

Comment: Why does the 500gb disk seem suspect? It's brand new...